# number in input field not higher than other input field

Tags: javascript, forms

I have two input fields in my contact form, in both fields it's only possible to fill in a number. My question is, is there a way that the number in field 1 can never be higher than the number in field 2?

I have looked everywhere but can't find a solution. Is this even possible (with Javascript)? Hopefully somebody has a solution or can send me in the right direction.

```
<form>
<input type="number" class="fieldone" min="0" max="16" step="0.1">
<input type="number" class="fieldtwo" min="0" max="16" step="0.1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function forceLimit(e) {
   var limit = e.target.getAttribute("max");
   if(e.target.value > limit)
     e.target.value = limit;
}

function handleLimitChange(e) {
  var limit = e.target.value;
  var fieldOne = document.querySelector('#field-one');
  if(fieldOne.value > limit) {
     fieldOne.value = limit;
  }
  fieldOne.setAttribute('max', limit);
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="number" id="field-one" class="fieldone" onchange="forceLimit(event)" min="0" max="16" step="0.1">
<input type="number" id="field-two" class="fieldtwo" onchange="handleLimitChange(event)" min="0" max="16" step="0.1">
</form>
```

Comment: I am able to type or paste any number I like in to the first input.

Comment: @Turnip true, somehow if you fill it in it allows you to go beyond the max number, if you use the arrows you can't. I will find a different solution to that problem, for now this solution is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This is almost exactly what I am looking for, thank you! The only thing I notice is that if you fill in the second field first and then fill in the first it won't adjust anymore.

Comment: @ErwinvanEkeren it wont adjust because I hadnt set a listener for that. I can update the answer if you want to reset anytime there is a value update in the first one too

Comment: @ErwinvanEkeren check now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to check that always the value in field 2 is greater or equal to field 1:

```js
$('.fieldone').change(function(){
  checkValue();
});

$('.fieldtwo').change(function(){
  checkValue();
});

function checkValue(){
  var maxValue = $('.fieldtwo').val();
  if(maxValue > 0 && $('.fieldone').val() > maxValue){
    $('.fieldone').val(maxValue);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="number" class="fieldone" min="0" max="16" step="0.1">
<input type="number" class="fieldtwo" min="0" max="16" step="0.1">
</form>
```

Comment: @Erwin van Ekeren the example its working with jQuery 3.3.1 and this is the version that I used in the example above

Comment: Works great as well, great solution for someone who wants to use jQuery.